# Problem related to Lusin theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be real valued Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^k$,prove that there exists Borel functions $g$ and  h,s.t.:$g(x)=h(x)$a.e.and $g(x)\leq f(x)\leq h(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$.

First,thanks for your concentration!For this problem,i think of Lusin's theorem immediately,however,the Lusin theorem
can not give the relation of size to the f and g,thus it makes me confusion.

Comment: Idea: prove the result first for $f$ the indicator function of a Lebesgue measurable set. Then approximate positive functions and then arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks. It truly works!The proof is very similar to the proof of Lusin theorem!